# Development workflow for docker-compose: run a dev-version container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a quite typical docker-compose setup: a custom web container and a database container directly from docker hub. For development, my host directory is mounted into the web docker so that I do not have to rebuild container each time I do a minor change. The web server is a Passenger (standalone) serving a ruby app.

When I run it, I have my database running, my web service running (on port 3000), all good. However, if I do a change, nothing changes as the web server (passenger) needs to be relaunched. I would like to have to be able to launch a simple lightweight development server such as `thin` that I would restart manually when I do a change.

What I tried:

- Launching a new web container (`docker-compose run web ...`) does not expose any port for the new container. So, I cannot connect to the web server.
- Launching a new web container with Docker directly (`docker run web -p 5000:5000 image_name ...`). We loose the docker-compose functionality, the container is not linked to the database without manual bindings.
- Relaunching the docker-compose each time (as it starts quickly). Each time my database is relaunched so empty, I need to keep running.
- Use `--service-ports` arg: do not work as port 3000 is already used
- `docker exec` my dev server on the web container: has to run on another port, so will not be exposed.
- `docker exec` the `kill` of my webserver: actually it works (it restarts), but I do not really like this solution. Firstly, because the server is still Passenger where I would prefer a lightweight web server (as `thin`). Secondly, I find it not very clean to connect to kill over and over the server with `docker exec ...`.
- Changing my `Dockerfile` to replace Passenger by an auto-relaunching dev web server: I like the `Dockerfile` to be the same as on the prod server, tests, and dev.

Would you have a clean and easy way of just launching my web container, with port 5000 open, on which I would a shell the launch/relaunch a dev web server ?

Comment: I've just moved all the source code into a data container that is exported using SMB to the developer. I wrote Docker Shell for this purpose - http://dockershell.io/.

Answer (score 3):

I use two docker-compose files, one for development and one for production.

In development the docker-compose file you can override the `CMD` from your Dockerfile with `command` so you can easily use `bash` to have a shell or use an auto relaunch server.

To use you custom docker-compose file do : `docker-compose -f dev.yml ...`

And for this :

> Relaunching the docker-compose each time (as it starts quickly). Each time my database is relaunched so empty, I need to keep running.

If you do `docker-compose up --no-deps web` it will not relaunch your db

Comment: So you are saying you run a docker compose with a database, and some dev server that just starts bash? Can you give a example of that ? I am seeking to start a mongo, a elasticsearch and a dev server without the server running (just bash it after the run)